# Query documents with a greater value than the average in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have messages in ElasticSearch. I have the sender of the message and the length of the message in two different fields. I can get the average message length grouped by message sender with the following query:

```
POST /document/_search?pretty
{
    "aggs": {
        "app": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "message_sender"
        },
            "aggs": {
                "avg_length": {
                    "avg": {
                        "script" : "doc['message_length'].values[0]?.toInteger()"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Note: I know it looks weird, but the length of the message is stored as a string, that's why I have to convert it to an integer.)

My problem is: how can I list out the messages which are longer than the average of their group? So if sender_1's average message length is 100, then list out the messages greater than that.

I was trying to use the selector bucket but with no results. I'm basically asking how can I have a feature similar to SQL HAVING in ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You might look at: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4404 where this feature is discussed. They implemented pipeline aggregations which might help you but are not exactly what you want here.

You should just query two Times. First get the average and then get the messages.