# Elastic Search: get documents where value > AVG

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hi I would like to understand how deep you can go with Elastic Search queries.

I have an index with a property "Price" and i would extract any document where Price > AVG(Price).

For example if I have 6 documents with this prices:

532,400,299,100,100,33

it should extracts documents 299, 400, 532 because > of price average (244).

I can reach this goal with simple elastic search query or I need to use something else, for example scripting (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) or custom script with another language (nodejs, python, .Net etc) or use some ETL tool like Logstash?

I have some difficulties to identify the road. I tried to use subquery in ES using query but it's not supported.

({ "query" : "select * from myIndex where Price > (select avg('Price') from myIndex) "})

Answer (score 2):

I think this query will solve your problem in efficient way:

```
{
   "aggs":{
      "price_gte_244":{
         "filter":{
            "range":{
               "price":{
                  "gte":244
               }
            }
         },
         "aggs":{
            "avg_price":{
               "avg":{
                  "field":"price"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When **244** could be any value/variable that you want

If you want to read more about filter aggregation: [Filter aggregation docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)

Comment: Thanks Bizzu, ok but my actual average 244 is dynamic (for example if we removed one document the average change). My question is how to pass dynamic average where you insert 244 in your example?

Comment: It depends on how you send your request - if you do that from curl, make sure you change the body before you send it.  if you do that by some client (java, c#, python, etc..) make sure you send the variable of the average to the function

Comment: I'am trying to evaluate if it is possible to reach the goal from kibana or if I need to create a logic via NEST in C# or Python. If, as it seems, achieving the goal (with kibana, with an ES watcher, or with a painless script) is complicated, then I will proceed with a custom script via C#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640123/query-documents-with-a-greater-value-than-the-average-in-elasticsearch maybe this will answer you question, In my opinion, if you don't have access to the writer of the documents - do 2 queries - one calculate the avg and the second is what I suggested. if you have access you could calculate the total elements and the total price in-memory and reduce the first query that I suggested (this operation is very light in terms of CPU and Memory consumption)

Comment: Thanks Bizzu for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your data is structured, you can get the avg value across all of your documents through an [AVG aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html). Then, use that value in a [Range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) to find the documents greater than this value. You can also look into the [Bucket Selector Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) which has a lot of similarity with a SQL HAVING clause.

Comment: My difficulty is how to pass aggs name (avg_price in my sample) in the range query. Can you suggest me with an example?

Comment: Can you run the avg aggregation and take the acual value it returns to use as the value in the range query? So if the avg agg returns 243, you build your range query using the value 243 as opposed to a variable?

Comment: No the query must be atomic and dynamic. I need to create a kibana dashboard with the alerts when the doc Price is greater then averagePrice group by some fields in a datarange.